Prevent Serilog from writing default event for specific HTTP Client
If I add the following piece of lines in my app settings of .NET Web API then it stops logging the HTTP events by default :
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Warning",
    "System.Net.Http.HttpClient": "None"
  }
}

How can I customize it in such a way that it should only impact the Http Client I am using, not all Http Clients in the System?
I a using Refit Client and I want to apply this settings only for it how can I achieve that for Serilog ?
